# How to debug the mono runtime calling seemingly random getter instead of interface method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, interface, mono, vtable

I have an issue caused by the mono runtime calling a seemingly random getter instead of interface method.

I've narrowed the core of it down to:

```
IGraphElementEditorData test = provider.CreateEditorData();

if (!typeof(IGraphElementEditorData).IsAssignableFrom(test))
{
    Debug.LogWarning("Please don't get logged.");
}
```

Unfortunately, it gets logged:

[image: The log]

Obviously, the runtime is doing something wrong here, breaking type safety.

The program is running on Unity's Mono 2.X runtime.

Investigating further, I found out that `provider.CreateEditorData()` actually calls an entirely different method on the provider itself: it calls the getter of `provider.source`, which is not even type compatible:

```
0x0000000031E8E84B (Mono JIT Code) Bolt.InvalidConnection:get_source ()
0x000000003493D53F (Mono JIT Code) Bolt.UnitConnection`2<object, object>:Ludiq.IConnection<Bolt.IUnitOutputPort,Bolt.IUnitInputPort>.get_source ()
0x00000000321F719A (Mono JIT Code) Ludiq.GraphPointer:GetElementEditorData<object> (Ludiq.IGraphElementEditorDataProvider)
```

The provider type is in a complex inheritance chain involving interfaces, abstract classes and generics, and I wouldn't even know how to begin isolating the issue at this point.

I'm asking **how can I approach debugging this?** It is the first time I encounter an issue like that and I'm not familiar with Mono runtime terminologies enough to even begin searching. From what I understand, it seems like it could be an issue with the virtual table (vtable) of method pointers, but I can't find a bug report on the Mono tracking software that matches my issue.

Answer (score 1):

`IsAssignableFrom` [accepts a `Type` parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx). The object you are passing in is an object *of type* `IGraphElementEditorData` which is *not* a `Type` (and cannot be<sup>1</sup>), which should be throwing a compiler error "cannont convert from IGraphElementEditorData to Type"

What you are probably looking for is:

```
IGraphElementEditorData test = provider.CreateEditorData();

if (!typeof(IGraphElementEditorData).IsAssignableFrom(test.GetType()))
{
    Debug.LogWarning("Please don't get logged.");
}
```

In any case, when I run this code, I do *not* get the logging message.

<sup>1</sup> Interfaces cannot extend classes.